# Confusion about "asio::async_compose"" vs "asio::async_initiate"

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

I am slowly understanding the asio way of doing things as I migrate legacy callback code to use completion tokens.  So far I have been following the pattern described in the `callback_wrapper.cpp` example which uses `asio::asio::async_initiate`. Then I was reading the article "[The great mystery on how to make durable, asynchronous functions for asio.](https://lastviking.eu/asio_composed.html)" and the author uses `asio::async_compose` instead. Is there an advantage of one over the other? The API looks similar save for one takes generic arguments and the other an io context and executor with the arguments supplied via the wrapped function. Is it just a difference between being able to have bi-directional data flow via the lambda capture vs uni-directional via the arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Also new to asio, but after reading the official composed xx examples (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp20_examples.html), I think the difference appears **when you need to compose multiple asynchronous operations** (for example, wait for some timer and then send messages by socket).

You need to create an intermediate completion handler if you use *async_initiate*, via a struct or lambda or something else, like the *intermediate_completion_handler* in *composed_5.cpp* and *composed_6.cpp*.
The intermediate handler is passed to the intermediate initiating functions like the async_wait of a timer.

However, if you use *async_compose*, you can omit this by just passing the asynchronous operation implementation (the first parameter of *async_compose*) to the intermediate initiating functions.
async_compose takes care of generating the intermediate completion handler, as the comment in the examples says:

> The first argument to our lambda is a reference to the enclosing
> intermediate completion handler. This intermediate completion handler
> is provided for us by the boost::asio::async_compose function, and
> takes care of all the details required to implement a conforming
> asynchronous operation. When calling an underlying asynchronous
> operation, we pass it this enclosing intermediate completion handler
> as the completion token.

So if you just want to wrapping some one-shot callback interface, both is available, but if you want to combine multiple operations into one, *async_compose* may be a better choice.